# How to inject a non-serializable class (like java.util.ResourceBundle) with Weld

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld

I want to create a Producer that makes it possible to inject a java.util.ResourceBundle into any class in order to get localized Strings easily. My ResourceBundle-Producer looks like this:

```
public class ResourceBundleProducer {
  @Inject       
  public Locale locale;

  @Inject       
  public FacesContext facesContext;

  @Produces
  public ResourceBundle getResourceBundle() {
    return ResourceBundle.getBundle("/messages", locale )
  }
}
```

The Injection of Locale and FacesContext works (took the corresponding producers from the Seam 3 Alpha Source). But unfortunately, ResourceBundle is not Serializable and therefore can't be produced in this way. I'm getting the following Error from Weld when trying to access a JSF-page which calls a bean that uses my ResourceBundle:

`Caused by: org.jboss.weld.IllegalProductException: WELD-000054 Producers cannot produce non-serializable instances for injection into non-transient fields of passivating beans\\n\\nProducer\: org.jboss.weld.bean-/D:/Program Files (x86)/GlassFish-Tools-Bundle-For-Eclipse-1.2/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/teachernews/applications/teachernews/-ProducerMethod-services.producers.ResourceBundleProducer.getResourceBundle()\\nInjection Point\: field web.PersonHome.bundle`

Are there any ways to get my ResourceBundleResolver to work? Or are there any other mechanisms to get a similar functionality?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Okay, i'll spent some of my hardly earned points ;)
Will also accept a good workaround for this issue!

I got another example where creating a Producer doesn't work: a FlashProducer. A FacesContext-Flash also cannot be produced because Flash isn't serializable.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, First of all ResourceBundle **is not Serializable**. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). And The message is clear

> cannot produce **non-serializable** instances for injection into **non-transient** fields of passivating beans

*passivating beans* ??? I Think *web.PersonHome* is Either a Stateful Session Bean or a @ConversationScoped bean. Am i right ??? If so you should **mark your bundle property as transient**

```
private transient @Inject ResourceBundle bundle;
```

Comment: @ifischer disclaimer: I do not use Weld yet. I use Seam. So i am not sure whether @Inject annotation can be used along with transient

Comment: Congratz, you just earned yourself 50 points ;) Finally a solution! Wonder why it took that long + a Bounty, as it's kind of easy (also wonder why i didn't find out by myself...). Just tested it, also works with CDI/Weld. Now i can finally inject Resourcebundles and Contexts.

Comment: BTW, PersonHome is a @ConversationScoped CDI/Weld-Bean (@Named)

Comment: @ifischer You are right. Because ConversationScoped must be serializable between requests, all of its fields must implements Serializable interface **unless you mark it as transient**. It explains why you get The error message. The same issue occurs with Stateful Session beans.

Comment: But with the `bundle` marked as `transient`, how can you be sure that it is available when you need it? In case of passivation/activation of the bean, the `ResourceBundle` is gone and access to it would rais an exception.

Comment: @MrD After a second though,, ResourceBundle is never allowed to stay Null as the app server will re-inject it afresh once detected as Null. This is a basic functionality of any container implementing IoC

Comment: @Sam but CDI-injection is only done once at creation time of the bean. So the "container" (i.e. Weld) will not recheck the values of it's fields after passivation/activation. Access to the field after passivation/activation will result in a NullPointerException.

Comment: `transient` fixes the exception but still I'm getting a warning triangle about unsatisfied dependencies. My `beans.xml` has `bean-discovery-mode="all"` in both projects (where the `@Cached` annotation and producer class is and where the `@Cached` is being `@Inject`) but still on both sides I'm getting it, like for `@Inject private CacheManager manager;`. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the diference between `private transient @Inject` and `@Inject private transient`? Using the former made IntelliJ error go away.`

Answer (score 5):

As per the comments thread in the accepted answer of Arthur. I followed [this blog](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/ejb-passivation-and-activation-example.html) as well as [this one](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/ejb-passivation-and-activation-example) to carry out a passivation/activation experiment. The experiment proved MrD comment that the transient property will be NULL upon activation. Thus, to deal with non-serializable member properties of a passivation capable bean (namely, sessionscoped, conversationscoped and stateful session beans), I suggest the following solution:

```
private ResourceBundle bundle;

@PostConstruct
@PostActivate
public void getResourceBundle() {
    bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/messages", locale );
}
```

This solution makes sure that the non-serializable property members are reinitialized every time it enters the READY state.

#### A final issue to address

A final issue to address is the injection of an SLF4j Logger which was non-serializable before slf4j 1.5.3, and [I quote](http://slf4j.org/faq.html#declared_static):

> As of SLF4J version 1.5.3, logger instances survive serialization.
>   Thus, serialization of the host class no longer requires any special
>   action, even when loggers are declared as instance variables.

Thus as long as your slf4j dependency is 1.5.3 or later you can safely inject an SLF4j Logger as follows:

```
@Produces
@LogbackLogger
public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
    return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
}
```

Assuming you declared the qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface LogbackLogger {
}
```

Then in a passivation-capable bean, inject as follows:

```
@Inject
@LogbackLogger
private Logger logger;
```

Comment: Concerning the "producer" for `ResourceBundle`: if I understand correctly, you're *not* using a producer for the `ResourceBundle` any more - loosing the charm of CDI. Instead you get the `ResourceBundle` manually on PostConstruct and -Activate events (btw: the PostConstruct and -Activate methods MUST NOT return a value).

So this is completely the non-CDI solution which could have been used in JEE5 too, isn't it?

Comment: @MrD Absolutely true!

Comment: @MrD I edited the initialization method as to return void. Thanks for your sharp eye.

Comment: I guess the annotation @PostConstruct should be removed so you can still make use of CDI

Comment: @Armando, I like your suggestion. I did not try it though... I wonder what MrD will say about it, he was right all along.