# How can I get a message bundle string from inside a managed bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, managed-bean, message-bundle

I would like to be able to retrieve a string from a message bundle from inside a JSF 2 managed bean. This would be done in situations where the string is used as the summary or details parameter in a `FacesMessage` or as the message in a thrown exception.

I want to make sure that the managed bean loads the correct message bundle for the user's locale. It is not clear to me how to do this from a managed bean using JSF API calls.

My configuration is:

- Using Tomcat 7 as the container so the solution cannot depend on API calls that only work in a full application server container
- Using the JSF 2 reference implementation (Mojarra)
- NOT using any libraries that allow CDI

**NOTE:** I did see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478073/jsf-2-localization-managed-bean), but it depends on features that are unavailable in my configuration

**EDIT:** I made a mistake in my original question. What I meant to ask was "How can I get a **resource** bundle string from inside a managed bean"? BalusC gave me the correct answer for what I asked. The solution for what I actually meant to ask is very similar:

```
public static String getResourceBundleString(
            String resourceBundleName,
            String resourceBundleKey)
        throws MissingResourceException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ResourceBundle bundle = 
        facesContext.getApplication().getResourceBundle(
            facesContext, resourceBundleName);
    return bundle.getString(resourceBundleKey);
}
```

Also, here is a link to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/jsf-when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle) that explains the difference between "message" bundles and "resource" bundles.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can get the full qualified bundle name of `<message-bundle>` by [`Application#getMessageBundle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getMessageBundle%28%29). You can get the current locale by [`UIViewRoot#getLocale()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getLocale%28%29). You can get a `ResourceBundle` out of a full qualified bundle
name and the locale by [`ResourceBundle#getBundle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29).

So, summarized:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String messageBundleName = facesContext.getApplication().getMessageBundle();
Locale locale = facesContext.getViewRoot().getLocale();
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(messageBundleName, locale);
// ...
```

---

**Update**: as per the mistake in the question, you actually want to get the bundle which is identified by the `<base-name>` of `<resource-bundle>`. This is unfortunately not directly available by a standard JSF API. You've either to hardcode the same base name in the code and substitute the `messageBundleName` in the above example with it, or to inject it as a managed property on `<var>` in a request scoped bean:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{msg}")
private ResourceBundle bundle; // +setter
```

Comment: I just tried this, but the `messageBundleName` is being set to null which causes a `NullPointerException` in the call to `getBundle()`.

Comment: My mistake. I was confused about resource bundle vs message bundle. See my edit of the original question.

Comment: The latter solution doesn't work. It reports NullPointerException for bundle.

Comment: @Emerald: Works for me and anyone else when following exactly the information provided in both the question and answer. Just press [Ask Question] button if you still can't figure out instead of polluting valid answers with misleading and uninformative "doesn't work" comments.

Comment: @BalusC this works for me only for message bundles in English and in German, but not in Bulgarian. Do you know why?

Answer (score 27):

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ResourceBundle bundle = context.getApplication().getResourceBundle(context, "msg");
String message = bundle.getString("key");
```

here is key is property name which you want to access from properties file .

```
       message = This is "message"
```

This entry is from messages.properites file. and "message" is "key" .

Comment: Indeed this works like a charm. I do wonder though why you need to speficy the context as a paramater.

Comment: "msg" is the variable defined in faces config

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to get String resource bundle in managed bean, using `baseName` or `varName` (see definition of each one below):

### Using varName:

`varName`: is the String representing the `<var></var>` in `<resource-bundle>`

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Application app = context.getApplication();
ResourceBundle bundle = app.getResourceBundle(context, varName);
String msg = bundle.getString("key");
```

### Using baseName:

`baseName`: The fully qualified name of the resource bundle (`<base-name>` in `<resource-bundle>`).

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Locale locale = context .getViewRoot().getLocale();
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale, loader);
String msg = bundle.getString("key");
```

Comment: Incorrect. `ResourceBundle#getBundle()` takes base name as 1st argument. Perhaps you're confused because you gave them both the same value.

Comment: @BalusC  I mixed up the varName and baseName in the code, but i corrected that, thanks for your notice