# Share properties files among composite components

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf-2, composite-component

I know I can put messages used by the "inputEditable" composite component into a .properties file in the directory structure below:

[image]

But is there a way for 2 or more composite components to share a .properties file? Say for example, if there is a message or text value that I want common among them all? Or even just 2 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this component quite frequently you could load it in a resource bundle and call your properties from there:

```xml
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>com.example.resources.BundleName</base-name>
    <var>inputEditable</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

And call using `#{inputEditable['yourVar']}`

Or if it isn't used quite often, you wouldn't need to load it as a resource bundle and you could then load the bundle in your view using `<f:loadBundle>` and variables called the same way.

### See also

- [Internationalization in JSF, when to use message-bundle and resource-bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668161/when-to-use-message-bundle-and-resource-bundle)
- [How can I get a message bundle string from inside a managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272945/jsf-2-how-can-i-get-a-message-bundle-string-from-inside-a-managed-bean)