# Handling application exceptions and bean validations in JSF2 managed bean

Tags: jsf-2, exception

I am building a JSF2 application with multi-lingual content.

1) Bean validation will be used for validating the form fields. I use ValidationMessages properties files to define locale specific error messages and use the `<h:message>` tag for displaying the correct error message on screen.

2) For application specific exceptions, I currently have a generic ApplicationException which is handled in managed bean methods. Inside the exception catch block, I set a "msg" field in the bean with a custom error message (For e.g: "The inventory cannot be updated as no matching product code found").
In the xhtml pages, I check if the "msg" string is not empty and display it on top of the page.

Is there a better way to handle display of success and error messages in JSF? 
Can I simply throw the ApplicationException in managed beans and have a generic handler to handle the exceptions and display messages in the relevant view?
I read https://weblogs.java.net/blog/edburns/archive/2009/09/03/dealing-gracefully-viewexpiredexception-jsf2, but I am not able to map it to my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it almost properly. The way for the component validations is the one to go. However, for your managed bean logic, it's not necessary to implement a custom `String` property in your bean. Just add the message you want in your action method and it will be displayed by the `h:messages` tag:

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
    "The inventory cannot be updated as no matching product code found","");
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.addMessage(null, message);
```

Using an [`ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html) for just displaying a message seems overcomplicated. It also won't work for asynchronous (Ajax) requests, unless you use a third party solution like Omnifaces.

**See also:**

- [JSF 2 Global exception handling, navigation to error page not happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410007/jsf-2-0-global-exception-handling-navigation-to-error-pagen-not-happening)

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBiker. How can I handle localization while setting messages in FacesContext? Should I define a separate resource bundle for this? (apart from ValidationMessages and resource-bundle used in JSF pages)?

Comment: There's no need for that, you can access the resource bundle either using EL expression or the JSF API in the managed bean side. Have [a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6272972/1199132).