# FacesMessage not localized by <message-bundle>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, localization, message

I have mapped `<message-bundle>` in faces-config and my messages are loaded (I can load them with https://stackoverflow.com/a/6272972/2037762 )
By definition https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/index.html if I insert faces message into context then it should be translated.

I returned message in validator

```
        FacesMessage msg =
                new FacesMessage("message_email_wrongFormat");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        throw new ValidatorException(msg);
```

but it doesn't localize.

Using primefaces 5, JSF2.2

Comment: yeah I had, thanks. I looked at source codes in javax.faces and it looks like even authors don't use the translation on view layer ... maybe I just misunderstood something

Comment: Where are you setting the Locale ? any related code ? You need somehow to update the ViewRoot's Locale.