# Invoking multiple properties in the faces-config jsf, I always invokes the resource?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

**I manage two properties** is one for the generic messages and one for each module belonging to my system, but the problem I'm having is that when invoking the first method **getMessage()** always invokes the properties of the resource, when it should go the message.

```
public class ResourceBundleUtil implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String MESSAGE_PATH = "messages";
    public static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "resources";
    private static HashMap<String, Object> messageBundles = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public static String getMessage(String key) {
        if (key == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
            if (locale == null) {
                locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
            }
            ResourceBundle messages = (ResourceBundle) messageBundles.get(locale.toString());
            if (messages == null) {
                messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle(MESSAGE_PATH, locale);
                messageBundles.put(locale.toString(), messages);
            }
            return messages.getString(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return key;
        }
    }

    public static String getResource(String key) {
        if (key == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
            if (locale == null) {
                locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
            }
            ResourceBundle messages = (ResourceBundle) messageBundles.get(locale.toString());
            if (messages == null) {
                messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle(RESOURCE_PATH, locale);
                messageBundles.put(locale.toString(), messages);
            }
            return messages.getString(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return key;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem I have is that the **getMessage()** method always invokes the **resource** propertie, when should the message:

```
if (messages == null) {
       messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle(MESSAGE_PATH, locale);
       messageBundles.put(locale.toString(), messages);
}
```

No enters the conditional, and noticed that comes with name value is **resource**.

Unlike the method **getResource()** if I notice that operating normally.

Please I could comment on that problem should, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that you store both kinds of bundles in single map. So if **resources** bundle is used first, it is added to map. The key is current locale (e.g. "en").

Then if you try to retrieve **messages** bundle with the same locale you in fact get **resources** bundle instead of **messages** one because you use the same key.

To solve this problem either use two separate maps or prepend key with bundle identifier like this:

```
messageBundles.put("resources_" + locale.toString(), messages);
```

Btw. you use standard Java bundles. More hints on how to use bundles defined in faces-config.xml can be found here:
[How can I get a message bundle string from inside a managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272945/jsf-2-how-can-i-get-a-message-bundle-string-from-inside-a-managed-bean)