# Accessing ResourceBundle as ManagedProperty Serialization Issue

Tags: jsf, serialization, jsf-2.2, resourcebundle, transient

first of all, sorry for my bad english!

in the following  managed Bean (ApplicationScoped), i access a ResourceBundle(.properties) as a @ManagedProperty. a ResourceBundle Object is not serializable, so i get in the Eclipse/Tomcat Console an Error saying that this object cannot be serialized/de-serialized.. etc.

> Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
>   java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted;
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.PropertyResourceBundle

i have 2 Questions to this issue:

- i think, JSF handles pre-defined(in faces-config.xml) `ResourceBundles` as **ApplicationScoped** beans. this means(if i understanding this correctly), this Object/Bean (ResourceBundle) is been stored somewhere somehow in a file (persistent storage). Now and since `ResourceBundle` is not serializable, then in which format is it been stored? and how JSF serves such "Beans"? serialized Objects are stored in files as Bytes, so how not serializable Objects are stored?
- in the following example, i would declare my `@ManagedProperty  ResourceBundle` as **transient** (due to serialization problem), but transient objects won't be stored in persistent storage (stateless), does this mean that with every call of the method `getConfigurationAttribute`(where i use this resourceBundle) will recreate/reload the ManagedPropery ResourceBundle since it is marked as transient?

**Your help is greatly appreciated.**

```
@ManagedBean(name="facesResource",eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class FacesResource implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2454454363100273885L;
    @ManagedProperty("#{FACES_CONFIG}")
    private ResourceBundle facesConfig;
    //private transient ResourceBundle facesConfig;

    ....
    private Map<String,Language> languagesMap;  
    private Map<String,Theme> themesMap;
    ....

    public FacesResource(){

    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("*** FacesResource init ....");
        try{
            ....
            this.initLanguages();
            this.initThemes();
            ....
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       

    public String getConfigurationAttribute(String attributeKey){
        return this.facesConfig.getString(attributeKey);
    }
    // ... other methods & getter/setter ...etc

}
```

**UPDATE:**

- the ResourceBundle in the FacesResource Bean is **independent** of the Request `Locale`, so its not a problem to load it in an ApplicationScoped Bean, BUT
- since i access/inject(as @ManagedProperty) this ApplicationScoped Bean in other SessionScoped Beans, which should be serialized, which means, that all attributes (resourceBundle included) should be serialized too, and here i got the Problem with Serialization/Deserializazion
- @BalusC: if i do like you suggest in your answer: `ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.text")`, i have to provide the baseName of the Bundle. BUT this is exactly what i want to avoid. i don't want to hardcode static Paths in java Source Codes), so that when the path changes(most unlikely, but for the Case), i don't like to change paths in Java Source Codes but only in faces-config.xml.
- and i cannot use `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getResourceBundle(facesContext, "bundleVarName");` because my Bean is marked with eager=true, which means, the `facesContext` is **NULL** at this moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *i think, JSF handles pre-defined(in faces-config.xml) ResourceBundles as ApplicationScoped beans.*

Nope. They are managed by `ResourceBundle` API itself. JSF just resolves them on a per-request basis based on the requested locale (otherwise it would affect the language of any user visiting the web application!). So, they are essentially request scoped. But this all has further nothing to do with serialization. The `ResourceBundle` class is simply never intented to be serializable. It just lazily loads the bundles in Java's memory.

You'd best just do the same. Lazy loading it if it becomes `null` after deserialization. You only shouldn't evaluate `#{FACES_CONFIG}`, because it would be dependent on request locale. Provided that you can only use JSF `<resource-bundle><var>`, then you'd best load them via `Application#getResourceBundle()`. Provided a resource bundle var name of `FACES_CONFIG`, here's an example:

```
private transient ResourceBundle facesConfig;

public ResourceBundle getFacesConfig() {
    if (facesConfig == null) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        facesConfig = context.getApplication().getResourceBundle(context, "FACES_CONFIG");
    }

    return facesConfig; 
}
```

By the way, the variable name `facesConfig` is very confusing. It namely suggests that it represents the contents of `faces-config.xml`.

#### See also:

- [java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294551/java-io-writeabortedexception-writing-aborted-java-io-notserializableexception)

Comment: thanks BalusC, i see your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272945/how-can-i-get-a-message-bundle-string-from-inside-a-managed-bean, and you suggested that we can use ResourceBundle as ManagedProperty, is it only  good for requestScoped Beans, because its loaded evry time since its in requestScope? the name FACES_CONFIG is related to the Project Name (YouFaces), not the faces-config.xml.

Comment: As resource bundles are request scoped, `@ManagedProperty` on a resource bundle indeed works in a request scoped bean only. It's however possible with CDI `@Inject` with little help of a custom producer. As per your question update, you should just be able to get hand of `FacesContext` in `@PostConstruct`, even in an eagerly initialized application scoped bean. I updated the answer to just do the job in the lazy loading getter.

Comment: thank you very much BalusC. would you please explaine to me why/how is FacesContext available before/without any  Request? i thought FacesContext is only available after the most first request.

Comment: During startup there's a special "init" `FacesContext`. It will have all application wide stuff ready in a.o. `getApplication()`, but e.g. the methods of `ExternalContext` may indeed not have the desired effects at that point. But you don't need them in such case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use @ManagedProperty on a not Serializable Type.

Is it a resource bundle for localized Strings?

Read this: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/

```java
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = facesContext.getApplication()
                                       .getResourceBundle(facesContext, "bundleName");
```

Comment: thanks, but since JSF 2.2, i can access ResourceBundle as @ManagedProperty!

Comment: Oh, i didn't see the tag "jsf-2.2". I don't know much about 2.2 version, but i keep my point about using @ManagedProperty on not Serializable Type.
I think you can only access a single property of bundle mapped on faces-config.xml. "@ManagedProperty("#{bundleVar['property_text']}") String text".
You are sure that the Type is directly accessible? Where did you read about accessing the ResourceBundle in this way? I want read about it :)

Comment: yes the Type is directly accessible as @ManagedProperty i tested this. BUT if these Bundle depends on a Locale (not in my case), its only good practic in a requestScoped Beans. in my case, it causes serialization Problems, because i declare it in an ApplicationScoped Bean, then i inject this Bean in other SessionScoped beans, which must be serializable. so all attributes (ResourceBundle included) should be serialized, and here is the Problem!