# ManagedProperty is not changed when locale set programmatically

Tags: jsf, localization, jsf-2.2, managed-property

I defining my locales in faces-config.xml as descibed here: [JSF 2 localization (managed bean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478073)

And for the EL in my XHTML pages it is working. Even when I switch my language. 
But the `@ManagedProperty("#{msgs}")` in my managed bean is not changed.

How can I change the `@ManagedProperty` Locale ?

Comment: What's the scope of the bean?

Comment: It's a stateful session bean.

Comment: That's probably the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15757855/1530938