# How can I tell the CDI container to "activate" a bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, cdi

Suppose I have some class with injections:

```
class MyBean {

    @Inject
    Helper helper;

    // all sorts of data
}
```

and this class was created in a way the CDI container is not aware of it like reflection, serialization or `new`. In this case the `helper` is `null` because the CDI did not initialize it for us.

Is there a way to tell CDI to "activate" the bean or at least its injection? e.g., as if it was created with `Instance<MyBean>#get`?

Right now I have a hack where I do the following:

```
class SomeClass {

    @Inject
    Instance<MyBean> beanCreator;

    void activateBean() {
        MyBean mybean = ... // reflection/serialization/new
        MyBean realBean = beanCreator.get();
        Helper proxy = realBean.getHelper();
        mybean.setHelper(proxy);
        beanCreator.destroy(realBean);
    }
}
```

This looks pretty bad but it works for everything I tested. It just shows what the end result is that I want.

Using Wildfly 10.1 if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the way you use `MyBean` is not a CDI way; in fact you operate on so called non-contextual object. What you are doing is taking a non-CDI managed object and asking CDI to resolve injection points. This is quite unusual, as you handle part of the lifecycle (creation/destruction), while asking CDI to do the rest.

In your case, the `MyBean` class needs to become [`InjectionTarget`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#injectiontarget), and that is the way you should start looking. In order to trigger injection you will want to do something like this (during creation of `MyBean`):

```
// Create an injection target from your given class
InjectionTarget<MyBean> it = beanManager.getInjectionTargetFactory(beanManager.createAnnotatedType(MyBean.class))
                .createInjectionTarget(null);
CreationalContext<MyBean> ctx = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);
MyBean instance = new MyBean();
it.postConstruct(instance); // invoke @PostContruct
it.inject(instance, ctx); // trigger actual injection on the instance
```

Please note that this approach is usually clumsy (as in hard to make it work and maintain) and it might be better to instead turn your `MyBean` into a true CDI bean and leaving whole lifecycle management to CDI. For that, however, your question doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Thanks. The context: `MyBean` is part of a state object i need to save and load, currently with serialization (see my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828159/how-to-serialize-an-injected-bean)). I read that using injection in entities is not a good idea but this entity needs it. Also, where you write `new MyBean()` it can be replaced with deserialization or reflection, right?

Comment: Perhaps you should think about, if it is reasonable and necessary to give MyBean the responsibility it fulfills using Helper. Sometimes the structure is better, if you let some `Decorator`, `Adaptor` or even an `Iterator` handle that. These normally are beans which can be normal scoped created by the container and made able to work with your data-objects.

Comment: If you provide use case, of how the entity actually depend on such beans, then we can help refactor it to a much better design which will not require an injection into the entity. Ideally you should treat the entity as data, and have a separate bean to process that data

Comment: @Mark Yes, I think you can use deserialization. The point of that line in my sample is to obtain a reference to actual instance. So it should work.

Comment: Iv'e tested this and the bean's injection is `null` so it doesn't work as it is :(

Comment: @maress OK, I asked the design question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066680/how-to-alter-the-design-so-that-entities-dont-use-injections

Comment: @aschoerk See comment to maress above. Siliarus perhaps you can look there too please.